\renewcommand for adding letter to section not working properly
I am using \renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}} to add S to all the section numbers. This works well as long as the number is a single-digit (1-9), both in the document and the ToC. Once it becomes double-digit (10 or 11), it starts to misbehave in the ToC, like in the figure shown below (It is fine in the document). How can I fix this? It works well for the case of equation numbers.
I use \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}


Which document class do you employ? And, what part of the document is shown in the screenshot? The table of contents, maybe?

@Mico I updated the question with more details.
